# Bugzilla Login and create bug

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I been Googling reading trying week ago to do the following. I want to use Bugzilla API to create a new bug using PHP. There is an API so I don't want to work around but the problem is I can't login using the API.

I am using CodeIgniter FW and I found this after a long days of searching and reading:

```
public function tryBugZilla()
{
    $this->load->library('xmlrpc');
    $this->xmlrpc->server('http://link/xmlrpc.cgi', 80);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('User.login');

    $request = array('Bugzilla_login'=>'login', 'Bugzilla_password'=>'pass', 'product'=>'Your Product Name', 'component'=>'User Submitted', 'summary'=>'Test', 'version'=>'x.x', 'description'=>'asdas');

    $this->xmlrpc->method('Bug.create');
    $this->xmlrpc->request(array(array($request, 'struct')),'struct');

    if(!$this->xmlrpc->send_request()) {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
    }

    // this returns ticket ID
    print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
    //i get this:
    // No data received from server

}
```

This is the source [of the code](http://seeboriscode.blogspot.com/2011/02/bugzilla-api-request-via-php.html)

My Bugzilla version is 4.0.2

Also how can I use the Bugzilla REST API with PHP if its possible a sample code just for login I will continue

Comment: Have you tried a simple method like Bugzilla.version?

Comment: Also no data received from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to use Zend libraries, then this might work for you:

http://petehowe.co.uk/2010/example-of-calling-the-bugzilla-api-using-php-zend-framework/

Also, here's a tutorial on using Zend with CI:

http://www.gotphp.com/codeigniter-with-zend-framework-libraries/54312/